# Questions about masters admission in Canadian universities

Tags: masters

I currently have a 1.96 CGPA due to me failing some first year math courses. But, all but one of my third year/fourth year courses have been either a 3.7 or a 4.0 GPA. Unfortunately, I took a third year complex analysis course this semester as part of my Math Major but I barely got a 57 in the course. That being said, I'm also a stats major and all my other third year stats and math classes have been either a 3.7 or 4.0. Also got 2 years of work experience for one of the biggest companies in Canada as a Data Analyst Intern and my references are pretty strong as well.

I will be primarily trying for a Masters in Data Science/Data Analytics programs at RyeU, Uoft or UBC. My question is, how badly will the 1.96 CGPA affect my admission process. My last 2 years GPA (which Canadian universities look at) would be around a 3.3 - 3.7 per semester. And how badly would a third year math course affect my chances because my masters degree won't be in math but in stats (which I've done good in).

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely hard to say without consulting the individual programs; I would suggest writing to the administrative contact for the programs you are interested in (although you might not get an answer).

The answers would depend on

- any mandatory thresholds; my (Canadian) university has a university-wide policy for master's admissions requiring

> B+ (B- for Engineering) minimum average, based on a full year equivalent of final year courses (3rd/4th level) relevant to the program

(you should be OK under this rule).

- how competitive the program is; if there are other students with better GPAs, you might fall to the bottom of the list (and not even have the rest of your application reviewed carefully)
- how much the particular program is looking at elements other than grades
- I, personally, would worry that uneven grades might indicate that you had a hard time motivating yourself to work on topics you didn't enjoy; while there's no way to prove that the issues that led to your poor grades wouldn't repeat themselves in a master's program, you should definitely address/explain these grades in the narrative section of the application.